# Function keys and Hot are switched

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, shortcuts

I recently got a new laptop and installed 12.10 on it. I noticed right away that the "hot keys" on the F keys didn't always do what was pictured and also I noticed that the "hot keys" and the function keys were reversed. e.g. to close a window I have to hit alt-fn-F2 instead of just alt-F2. This is pretty annoying because I've been using the same keyboard shortcuts for years and I don't really want to have to re-learn them.

I would also like to switch what the hot keys do, for example the F3 key is pictured as increase screen brightness but it really puts the computer to sleep. I would like to change this back to increase the brightness

I looked in keyboard shortcuts settings but these options are not in there. I also downloaded gconf-editor but was unable to find where to change the shortcuts on it. (they weren't at apps \ metacity \ keybinding_commands like others described)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Check in your bios settings (I had the same problem)

On my HP G62 notebook: *System Configuration* → *Action Keys* → *Disabled*

[image]

If you have a different machine, this may be named differently or found in another section of the setup utility.